# Force setsockopt in python by replacing socket() method

Tags: python, sockets

I need to do a `SO_MARK` `setsockopt` on a socket, but the module (`dnspython` in my case) does not support that. So I want to replace the standard `socket()` method so that when `dnspython` calls that in `dns.query.udp` method - the `socket()` is my replaced one.

How do I best do that in Python?

Comment: `def my_custom_socket(...):... ; socket.socket = my_custom_socket`?

Comment: I believe it should be like `dns.query.socket.socket = my_custom_socket` - the method you described does not work for sure

Comment: `dns.query.socket` is exactly the same as `socket`.  Monkey-patching one is the same as monkey-patching the other.  But if you monkey-patch `socket`, that will continue to work even if `dnspython` decides to rearrange their code in arbitrary ways.

Comment: Strangely but it does really work. I thought python imports are 'not-so-global'. Thanks!

Comment: Python imports live in `sys.modules`.  A module is imported at most once, unless it raises exceptions at import-time (in which case it could be imported again but would likely raise the same exception again).